# How do I select two different years to display in query?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I need to be able to write a report in Report Builder with the ability to select two years to compare side by side.

I currently have my query setup to display the year defined in the parameter:

```
DECLARE @ YR_CDE VARCHAR(4) = '2016'

**Select/From statement here**

WHERE YR_CDE = @YR_CDE
```

But this doesn't allow me to select multiple years when I throw the query into Report Builder. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Since YR_CDE is stored as a string, you could modify your query and do `WHERE YR_CDE BETWEEN @YR_CDE AND (@YR_CDE +/- number of years)` where the number of years is how ever many years you want your field to search.

Comment: `Where YR_CDE = '2016' OR YR_CDE = '2017'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @yr1 VARCHAR(4) = '2016',
        @yr2 VARCHAR(4) = '2017'

SELECT    <your-fields>
FROM      <your-table>
WHERE     yr_cde = @yr1
      OR  yr_cde = @yr2
```

If you are attempting to do a range of years, the following would work:

```
DECLARE @yr1 VARCHAR(4) = '2016',
        @yr2 VARCHAR(4) = '2018'

SELECT    <your-fields>
FROM      <your-table>
WHERE     yr_cde BETWEEN @yr1 AND @yr2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN in where clause as below:

```
Where YR_CDE in (@YR_CDE1, @YR_CDE2)
```